# Get the reduce of the array within array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to get the total of my `packings` array inside the `sku` array. I have `map`ped and `reduce`d the array, but it gives me an `undefined` output.

```
sku: [
  {
    id:1,
    value:0,
    packings: [
      {
        id: 1,
        cost: 0,
        code:'',
        pieces: 0,
        size:0,
        total:0
       },
    ],
  },
],
```

Here is my code:

```
let result = this.sku
    .map ( (obj,index) => {
        parseFloat(obj.packings.total);
        console.log(obj.packings.total)
    })
    .reduce( (total,current) => {
        total+current;
    }) 

return this.fixFourDecimal(result);
```

Note that `sku` and `packings` are dynamic, and the user can add/multiply `packings` inside one `sku`, and can add many `sku`s too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use curly braces `{}` inside an arrow function `=>` it does not let you implicit return - you'd have to use the `return` keyword or refactor your function:

```
let result = this.sku
  .map((obj, index) => {
    console.log(obj.packings.total);
    return parseFloat(obj.packings.total);
  })
  .reduce((total, current) => total + current);
```